# AWK filter rows with valid numbers or empty

Tags: regex, awk, floating-point, is-empty, scientific-notation

I try to use `awk` to filter some rows based on whether a given column contains an integer, floating point or empty string.

I have problems with the integers or the way to add them to the rule but avoiding adding weird expressions like `2.e`.

###### INPUT:

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2251,2.e
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2255,3.a
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
220802,2258,N/A
```

###### EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
```

I try this, but fails:

```bash
awk -F , '$3 ~ /(^$|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+e?[-+]?[0-9]?+)/' INPUT
```

```
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
```

Also try this:

```bash
awk -F , '$3 ~ /(^$|[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+e?[-+]?[0-9]?+)/'
```

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2251,2.e
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2255,3.a
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
```

**Any aproach to consider?**
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for empty is easy. You could use `$3~/^$/` (as in your regex) but in this case, as you will also test if the field is a number, it's even shorter to logically "not" it, making use of the fact that only empty string and numbers equal to zero (`0`, `0.0`, `-0`, etc) are false.

To test if awk considers a field (or variable) to be a number, you can compare it to itself plus zero.

So:

```
awk -F, '$3~/^$/ || ($3+0 == $3)' INPUT
```

or:

```
awk -F, '!$3 || ($3+0 == $3)' INPUT
```

---

The reason your regex didn't work is that you didn't anchor it. For example, `[0-9]+` matches if there is a digit, even when it is embedded in something that is not a number.

Matching all valid representations of number is quite error-prone.

Comment: Clever! I liked it. It is simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `AWK` manual provides [Isnumeric](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Isnumeric-Function.html) which seems to work for your example, let `file.txt` content be

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2251,2.e
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2255,3.a
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
220802,2258,N/A
```

then

```
awk 'function isnumeric(x,  f)
{
    switch (typeof(x)) {
    case "strnum":
    case "number":
        return 1
    case "string":
        return (split(x, f, " ") == 1) && (typeof(f[1]) == "strnum")
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
BEGIN{FS=","}length($3)==0||isnumeric($3,arr)' file.txt
```

gives output

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
```

Explanation: I use `length` (which is built-in function) to detect were 3rd column is zero-length string and `isnumeric` function copied from manual to detect if it is numeric, if at least 1 of conditions is met line is printed. You might elect to test it for certain corner-cases to check if function does works as you want.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: definitely gawk-specific but nice to know about

Comment: I like the strictness of using functions and cases. Unfortunately the script is usually installed on CentOS7 systems to which I can't update the gawk version (4.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1** : trying to account for all numbers large and small, including comma-delimited financial figures, even for `awks` that don't have built-in capabilities for big-ints and big-floats :

```
—( excluding all potential variations for **NaNs** or **INFinities** )
```

> ```
> echo '4.0000000000000000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999
>         9999999999999999999999999999999944444444e506' |
>
> {m,n,g}awk '(_=$-__)<=+_ || 
>             /^[+-]?([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?((,[0-9][0-9][0-9])
>                   *|[0-9]*))?([.][0-9]*)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/'
> ```

```
4.0000000000000000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999
  9999999999999999999999999999999944444444e506
```

This `big-float` is approx `1682.8956160-bits` in size, definitely mandating a special library to process it properly, since even octuple precision falls far short.

=========================================

for the shown samples :

> ```
> mawk '$NF <= +$NF' FS=','
> ```

```
220802,2249,3
220802,2250,37.5
220802,2252,28
220802,2253,
220802,2254,19.5
220802,2256,123.25
220802,2257,1.32e-8
```